# Simplification of integral of partial derivatives product

Tags: calculus

I'm not sure if this integral can be simplified:

$$
\int \left ( \frac{\partial }{\partial x} f(x,y) \right )\cdot \left ( \frac{\partial }{\partial y} \frac{\partial }{\partial x} f(x,y) \right ) \partial x
$$

Have been trying using with integration by part and the chain rule, but I can't get anything decent. Any hint on how to proceed, or if you think it is at all "simplifiable" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int \left ( \frac{\partial }{\partial x} f(x,y) \right )\cdot \left ( \frac{\partial }{\partial y} \frac{\partial }{\partial x} f(x,y) \right ) \partial  x
=\frac12\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\int   (\frac{\partial }{\partial x} f(x,y))^2\partial  x$$